# Accessing custom property value of webpart in application page

Tags: web-part

We have a custom property in a webpart. and we are opening an application page as a popup dialog. In that page we want to access the webpart property.

The custom property is as follows:

```
[Category("PULSE Survey")]
    [Personalizable()]
    [WebDisplayName("Welcome Text:")]
    [WebDescription("Welcome Text is")]
    [WebBrowsable]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "WelcomeText")]
    public string WelcomeText
    {
        get
        {
            return _welcomeText;
        }
        set
        {
            _welcomeText = value;
        }
    }
```

Please help me with the same.
Thank you in advance